# Getting wrong UIButton tag on Long press gesture recognizer

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uibutton, uigesturerecognizer

I am aware that there are already many questions asked similar to this, but I have tried all of them, and on failing to solve my issue I am posting my question. First the questions I tried are:

1)[How to get button.tag via longPressGestureRecognizer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700984/how-to-get-button-tag-via-longpressgesturerecognizer)

2)[UIButton Long Press Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179347/uibutton-long-press-event)

In my application I have 12 `UIButtons` in my xib. On the long press of `UIButton` I have this method getting called. Using `gesture.view.tag` property always gives me same tag(i.e) every time when I click on different `UIButtons`.

```
- (IBAction)longPress:(id)sender {

     UILongPressGestureRecognizer* gesture=(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)sender;
     NSLog(@"Tag---> %d",gesture.view.tag);
  }
```

My xib looks something like this:

[image]

> **Update 1:**

Before someone gets confused with xib, I must say that `UIButtons` are set to Custom type so they are invisible under `UIImageView`.

Comment: It will crash. Sender is `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`. It does not have tag property. it's view that is `UIButton` will have tag property. Kindly refer to [Richard j Ross's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/427309/richard-j-ross-iii) answer. Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: Yep I noticed in regard to the Gesture Recognizer, I believe RJR's solution is correct

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears that a `UIGestureRecognizer` can be tracking more than one view, but it does not report that it is tracking more than one view. Thus, when you check the `view` property of a `UIGestureRecognizer`, it is set to the last view that the recognizer was added to.

From the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> A gesture recognizer operates on touches hit-tested to a ***specific view*** and all of that view’s subviews. It thus must be associated with that view. To make that association you must call the UIView method addGestureRecognizer:. A gesture recognizer does not participate in the view’s responder chain.

The solution in this scenario is to have a gesture recognizer for each view that needs recognizing, and have them linked to the same delegate selector.

<sub>Note: this question (and my answer) originated in the [NSChat chat room, on March 20th, 2013.](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8376090#8376090) It was decided to post here for future reference.</sub>

Comment: Thanks Richard for the Note.